# Problem with point position in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am quite new to tikz and I am trying to draw a circle with points regularly positioned on it. My code works well if I ask lower or equal to 46 points. For more points everyting is going wrong (points are mispositioned) but there is no error message with the compilation.

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{article} % I'm in France.

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,arrows}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \sffamily 

    \newcommand{\rayon}{5cm} % Rayon du cercle en cm (radius of the circle)
    \newcommand{\nbPt}{46} % Nombre de points sur le cercle (Number of points on the circle)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nb}{\nbPt-1}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw(0,0) circle (\rayon); % Tracer le cercle (Draw the circle)
            \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\nb} {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360*\i/\nbPt};
                \draw(\angle:\rayon) node{+}; \draw(\angle:\rayon*1.08) node{\i};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

May be I do some mistakes but I can't find where. It will be great if someone can give me some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `pgf` uses TeX dimensions to do its mathematics. The maximum dimension it could handle is `16383.99998 pt` (TeX’s largest dimen). So, you have to change the order of this calculation `\pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360*\i/\nbPt};`. First divide by `\nbPt` then multiply by `\i` or just put two parens around `(\i/\nbPt)` to avoid large dimensions.

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{article} % I'm in France.

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,arrows}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \sffamily 

    \newcommand{\rayon}{5cm} % Rayon du cercle en cm (radius of the circle)
    \newcommand{\nbPt}{60} % Nombre de points sur le cercle (Number of points on the circle)
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nb}{\nbPt-1}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw(0,0) circle (\rayon); % Tracer le cercle (Draw the circle)
            \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\nb} {
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{360/\nbPt*\i};
                \draw(\angle:\rayon) node{+}; \draw(\angle:\rayon*1.08) node{\i};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this problem with tikz but I am not able to understand why this limit is reached here.

Comment: @OlivierMAES: `360*45 = 16200 < 16383.99998`, but `360*46 = 16560 > 16383.99998`, this is the limit you see in your example.

Comment: Ok that's now clear for me.